# how does a gradle task explicitly set itself having altered it's output or up to date for tasks dependent on it

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I am creating a rather custom task that processes a number of input files and outputs a different number of output files.

I want to check the dates of the input files against the existing output files and also might look at the content of the input files to make the determination whether it is up to date or needs to be invoked to become up to date.  What properties do I need to set in a doFirst, code the main action, or whatever   ( where and when) in my task to set the right state for their dependency checker and task executor so as either appropriately force dependents to build or not.

Also any doc on standard lib utilities to do things like file date checking etc, getting lists of files etc that are easy like in ruby rake.

How do I specify the inputs and outputs to the task ?  Especially as the outputs will not be known until the source is parsed and the output directory is scanned for what exists.

a sample that does this in a larger project that has tasks that are dependent on it would be really nice :)

Answer (score 1):

> What properties do I need to set in a doFirst, code the main action, or whatever ( where and when) in my task to set the right state for their dependency checker and task executor so as either appropriately force dependents to build or not.

Ideally this should be done as a custom task type. None of this logic should be in any of the Gradle files at all. Either have the logic in a [dedicated plugin project](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html) that gets published somewhere which you can then reference in the project, or have the logic in [`buildSrc`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_gradle_projects.html#sec:build_sources).

What you are trying to develop is what is known as an incremental task: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_tasks.html#incremental_tasks

These are used heavily throughout Gradle which makes the incremental build of Gradle possible: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:up_to_date_checks

> How do I specify the inputs and outputs to the task ? Especially as the outputs will not be known until the source is parsed and the output directory is scanned for what exists.

Once you have your tasks defined and whatever else you need, in your main Gradle files you would configure them as you would any other plugin or task.

The two links above should be enough to help get you started.

As for a small example, I developed a Gradle plugin that generates files based on some input that is not known until its configured. The 'custom' task type just extends the provided [`JavaExec`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.html). The custom task is [`Wsdl2java`](https://github.com/ciscoo/cxf-codegen-gradle/blob/v1.0.0-rc.1/cxf-codegen-gradle/src/main/java/io/mateo/cxf/codegen/wsdl2java/Wsdl2JavaTask.java). Then based on user configuration, tasks get registered [here](https://github.com/ciscoo/cxf-codegen-gradle/blob/v1.0.0-rc.1/cxf-codegen-gradle/src/main/java/io/mateo/cxf/codegen/CxfCodegenPlugin.java#L98..L105) using the input file from the user. Since I reused built-in task types, I know for sure that no extra work will done and can rely on Gradle doing the heavy lifting. There's also a test to ensure that [configuration cache](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/configuration_cache.html) works as expected: [ConfigurationCacheFunctionalTests](https://github.com/ciscoo/cxf-codegen-gradle/blob/v1.0.0-rc.1/cxf-codegen-gradle/src/functionalTest/java/io/mateo/cxf/codegen/ConfigurationCacheFunctionalTests.java).

As I mentioned earlier, the links above should be enough to get you started.

Comment: Thanks - I'm surprised there isn't a generic out of the box task that can do this without a lot of code just a way to set the state and put in an explicit test to say I output something or i'm up to date.  "the answr" will happen after I implement it :) thanks !

Comment: looks like you are creating a generic one as a plugin type where one can set the "script" as a configured item.

So will it only execute the script if any of the existing outputs are dated less than any of the inputs or the outputs are empty?   How does it handle setting a new outputs value ?

A lot is implicit in gradle but I assume anything that generates outputs when it is executed has to modify the outputs list for the cache system for it's dependents

I assume this is the same thing a java compiler has to do as it generates more class files than number of source files.

Comment: apparenlty the way this is done is by manipulating the "TaskOutputs" object and using the TaskOutputs "upToDateWhen" item where you test if the current outputs need to be regeenrated or not.

https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/TaskOutputs.html#upToDateWhen-groovy.lang.Closure-